# Rave Report that comes with Delphi 2006

Tags: delphi, bde, rave-reports

There is a software which is using BDE for its database activities.

The database is very awkwardly designed.

I have to build a few custom reports that will use the data generated by this software.

I have a need to skip a few records based on a few conditions.

Like for example if **Field4** and **Field5** = 0 then that record should not be printed but if **Field1 > Field2** of the same record then *only* **Field1** should be printed ***not*** other fields.

How can I achieve this Rave Report?

I have tried to achieve this with before print even in Rave Report but due to lack of proper documentation on this part I have not been able to make any headway. If someone can point me to where I can find enough documentation and a few example of how to program **Before Print** and **After Print** event I may be able to solve my problem.

Comment: What version of Delphi/Rave? Are you using the visual designer or are the reports in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the .rav is not embedded in the executable (yes, it's possible), you can modify the dataview and substitute the original ones to direct database dataviews. So, you can modify the report if the program just fire the report without further parametrization...... There is some documentation on the script engine of rave, in the help of visual editor and in the Nevrona site.

Of course, Nevrona needs to do better documentation...

Comment: Thanks for documentation link. I have selected you answer but I have to say that documentation is very scanty and what does exist is not really usable by a novice like me.

Comment: I never liked before, and was like when I got on 2-year a project that used rave like mad... I learned the hard way, but the Tips&Trick on nevrona site helped well. But I agree with you, documentation is not exactly the strong point of Rave.............

Answer (score 0):

you can always use query for your datasource, something like (i dunno about your table structure anyway)

```
select distinct * from table where field <> '0'
```

Comment: This is not possible as the original software is not available in source.
I just have to modify a few original reports as per clients requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation [here](http://www.nevrona.com/files/rppro4.pdf), with examples, to an older version but it should be pretty compatible with your version

Answer (score -1):

Don't blame me for this. I have never used Rave Report but this can be your last resort.

```
select CASE When (Field4>Field5) Then Field1 Else '' END AS Field1, ..... from Table where (Field4 <> 0 AND Field5<>0) OR (Field1>Field2)
```

Comment: This is not possible as the original software is not available in source. I just have to modify a few original reports as per clients requirements.